# In Ruby, how does coerce() actually work?

Tags: ruby, coercion, coerce, type-coercion

It is said that when we have a class `Point` and knows how to perform `point * 3` like the following:

```
class Point
  def initialize(x,y)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end

  def *(c)
    Point.new(@x * c, @y * c)
  end
end

point = Point.new(1,2)
p point
p point * 3
```

Output:

```
#<Point:0x336094 @x=1, @y=2>
#<Point:0x335fa4 @x=3, @y=6>
```

but then,

```
3 * point
```

is not understood:

> `Point` can't be coerced into `Fixnum` (`TypeError`)

So we need to further define an instance method `coerce`:

```
class Point
  def coerce(something)
    [self, something]
  end
end

p 3 * point
```

Output:

```
#<Point:0x3c45a88 @x=3, @y=6>
```

So it is said that `3 * point` is the same as `3.*(point)`. That is, the instance method `*` takes an argument `point` and invoke on the object `3`.

Now, since this method `*` doesn't know how to multiply a point, so

```
point.coerce(3)
```

will be called, and get back an array:

```
[point, 3]
```

and then `*` is once again applied to it, is that true?

Now, this is understood and we now have a new `Point` object, as performed by the instance method `*` of the `Point` class.

The question is:

1. Who invokes `point.coerce(3)`? Is it Ruby automatically, or is it some code inside of `*` method of `Fixnum` by catching an exception?  Or is it by `case` statement that when it doesn't know one of the known types, then call `coerce`?
2. Does `coerce` always need to return an array of 2 elements?  Can it be no array?  Or can it be an array of 3 elements?
3. And is the rule that, the original operator (or method) `*` will then be invoked on element 0, with the argument of element 1?  (Element 0 and element 1 are the two elements in that array returned by `coerce`.)   Who does it?  Is it done by Ruby or is it done by code in `Fixnum`?  If it is done by code in `Fixnum`, then it is a "convention" that everybody follows when doing a coercion?

   So could it be the code in `*` of `Fixnum` doing something like this:

   ```
   class Fixnum
     def *(something)
       if (something.is_a? ...)
       else if ...  # other type / class
       else if ...  # other type / class
       else
       # it is not a type / class I know
         array = something.coerce(self)
         return array[0].*(array[1])   # or just return array[0] * array[1]
       end
     end
   end
   ```
4. So it is really hard to add something to `Fixnum`'s instance method `coerce`?  It already has a lot of code in it and we can't just add a few lines to enhance it (but will we ever want to?)
5. The `coerce` in the `Point` class is quite generic and it works with `*` or `+` because they are transitive.  What if it is not transitive, such as if we define Point minus Fixnum to be:

   ```
   point = Point.new(100,100)
   point - 20  #=> (80,80)
   20 - point  #=> (-80,-80)
   ```

Comment: This is an excellent question! I'm so happy I've found it because this has been bothering me and until just now I didn't think it was solvable!

Comment: A great question. Thanks for putting it. It will save many engineer-confusion-hours, I'm sure.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Short answer: check out [how `Matrix` is doing it](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/lib/matrix.rb#L1268).

The idea is that `coerce` returns `[equivalent_something, equivalent_self]`, where `equivalent_something` is an object basically equivalent to `something` but that knows how to do operations on your `Point` class. In the `Matrix` lib, we construct a [`Matrix::Scalar`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/lib/matrix.rb#L1422) from any `Numeric` object, and that class knows how to perform operations on `Matrix` and `Vector`.

To address your points:

1. Yes, it is Ruby directly (check calls to [`rb_num_coerce_bin` in the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/numeric.c#L219)), although your own types should do too if you want your code to be extensible by others. For example if your `Point#*` is passed an argument it doesn't recognize, you would ask that argument to `coerce` itself to a `Point` by calling `arg.coerce(self)`.
2. Yes, it has to be an Array of 2 elements, such that `b_equiv, a_equiv = a.coerce(b)`
3. Yes. Ruby does it for builtin types, and you should too on your own custom types if you want to be extensible:

   ```
   def *(arg)
     if (arg is not recognized)
       self_equiv, arg_equiv = arg.coerce(self)
       self_equiv * arg_equiv
     end
   end
   ```
4. The idea is that you shouldn't modify `Fixnum#*`. If it doesn't know what to do, for example because the argument is a `Point`, then it will ask you by calling `Point#coerce`.
5. Transitivity (or actually commutativity) is not necessary, because the operator is always called in the right order. It's only the call to `coerce` which temporarily reverts the received and the argument. There is no builtin mechanism that insures commutativity of operators like `+`, `==`, etc...

If someone can come up with a terse, precise and clear description to improve the official documentation, leave a comment!

Comment: hm, doesn't transitivity actually makes a difference?  
For example, see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801241/in-ruby-how-to-implement-20-point-and-point-20-using-coerce

Comment: No, transitivity doesn't play any role and Ruby doesn't assume that `a - b` is the same as `-(b - a)` or anything like that, not even `a + b == b + a`. What makes you believe I'm wrong? Did you check the MRI source? Why not try to follow the direction I indicate?

Comment: I think the OP meant "symmetric" rather than "transitive".  In any case **I** want to know how you write `coerce` such that non-symmetric operators like `-` can be implemented in only one direction while keeping symmetric operators working both ways.  In other words `a + 3 == 3 + a` and `3 + a - 3 == a` but `3 - a` raises an error.

Comment: @OldPro by "symmetric" I assume you mean "commutative". But I agree, the OP probably meant commutative, not transitive. Transitivity has to do with relations (e.g. equality), not operations like addition/subtraction.

Comment: There is nothing that guarantees commutativity. Even when coercion is not involved. See for example http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2009/05/02/schizo-ruby-puzzle/

Answer (score 2):

I find myself often writing code along this pattern when dealing with commutativity:

```
class Foo
  def initiate(some_state)
     #...
  end
  def /(n)
   # code that handles Foo/n
  end

  def *(n)
    # code that handles Foo * n 
  end

  def coerce(n)
      [ReverseFoo.new(some_state),n]
  end

end

class ReverseFoo < Foo
  def /(n)
    # code that handles n/Foo
  end
  # * commutes, and can be inherited from Foo
end
```

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future: I think it's more recommended to use `[Foo.instantiate(n), self]` if it's easy to directly convert numbers into your format.