# In Ruby, can the coerce() method know what operator it is that requires the help to coerce?

Tags: ruby, class-design, coercion, coerce, type-coercion

In Ruby, it seems that a lot of coerce() help can be done by

```
def coerce(something)
  [self, something]
end
```

that's is, when

```
3 + rational
```

is needed, Fixnum `3` doesn't know how to handle adding a Rational, so it asks Rational#coerce for help by calling rational.coerce(3), and this coerce instance method will tell the caller:

```
# I know how to handle rational + something, so I will return you the following:
[self, something]
# so that now you can invoke + on me, and I will deal with Fixnum to get an answer
```

So what if most operators can use this method, but not when it is (a - b) != (b - a) situation?  Can coerce() know which operator it is, and just handle those special cases, while just using the simple  [self, something] to handle all the other cases where (a op b) == (b op a) ?  (op is the operator).

Comment: Why ask _three_ questions on `coerce` when I provided you with the answer in your first one?

Comment: i got a lot of insight from the previous posts.  this time i'd like to see if it is feasible to let the new class handle all new operations by swapping the operands, seeing the operator is fine with doing so, and handle only the case that swapping is not ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `coerce` is not to know what operation you are trying to perform. Its purpose is to bring the argument and `self` to a common ground. Additionally, same operators can be commutative in certain classes, and not in other (`Numeric#+` and `Array#+`, for example), so your small commutativity-based `coerce` exploit really won't pay off.

Instead of pushing your `coerce` to do what it's not intended to, you should create a new class instead (such as `ScalarPoint`, for example), and use it to interface scalar values with your `Point`:

```
class ScalarPoint
  attr_reader :val

  def initialize(val)
    @val = val
  end

  def +(arg)
    case arg
    when Point:
      Point.new(@val + arg.x, @val + arg.y)
    when ScalarPoint:
      ScalarPoint.new(arg.val + @val)
    else
      raise "Unknown operand!"
    end
  end

  # define other operators, such as * etc

  def coerce(arg)
    return [ScalarPoint.new(arg), self] if arg.is_a?(Numeric)
    raise "Can't handle"
  end
end
```

and

```
class Point
  def coerce(arg)
    [ScalarPoint.new(arg), self] if arg.is_a?(Numeric)
    raise "Can't handle"
  end
end
```

etc. (NB: code not tested)

Comment: What if there is no common ground? In my case, I have a class `Money`, I want that `Money + Money = Money` and `Numeric*Money = Money` but not `Money*Money = Money` and not `Numeric + Money = Money`. What should I do?

Comment: Then `coerce` is simply not for you. `*` is a method on the left side object, and it should be kept so (not just invert the operands willy-nilly). Think of this: why, in plain Ruby, `'a' * 3` works, and `3 * 'a'` doesn't? Regardless how tempting would it be to misuse `coerce` for this, it's simply not its point. If you need to have `Numeric * Money = Money`, you need to do it in `Numeric`, not in `Money`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is that you *can* know the operator by looking at the backtrace but you *shouldn't* do that.

That is not how the coerce mechanism of Ruby has been designed. As I answered in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799571/in-ruby-how-does-coerce-actually-work/2799899#2799899), `coerce` should return two equivalent values `[a, b]` such that `a.send(operator, b)` will work, whatever the operator.

Comment: actually, i was wondering too, why coerce has to return 2 operands and then let the caller invoke the operator on the first returned element?  Is it equally feasible or better that coerce takes an operand and an operator, such as "+" or "*", and let the coerce function deal with all calculations and return just 1 value?

Comment: yes, i was just under the impression that coerce() returning [self, other] is a very handy way to implement coerce(), but obviously it won't work for all cases.  But what if there is a class, where we allow  100 - (80,80), and allow 3 * (80,80), but won't allow (3,3) * (80,80)?  In that case, the coerce function needs to return two Point objects, and invoke "*" on it, which the class is not to allow.

Comment: Please read my answer to your previous question. It'll show you that you can return a temporary wrapper (say Point::Scalar) which will handle the operators the way you want.