# Is there a better way to "monkey-patch" Ruby's base classes?

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

For a geometry library I'm writing I want to support multiplication of vectors by scalars, easy enough to do for `vector * scalar` by just defining the `Vector#*` method.  However to support `scalar * vector` all the `Fixnum#*`, `Bignum#*` and `Float#*` methods have to be monkey-patched.  I'm using the following code for each of these classes to accomplish that:

```
class Fixnum
  old_times = instance_method(:'*')

  define_method(:'*') do |other|
    case other
    when Geom3d::Vector
      Geom3d::Vector.new(self * other.dx, self * other.dy, self * other.dz)
    else
      old_times.bind(self).(other)
    end
  end
end

class Bignum
  #...
end

class Float
  #...
end
```

I'm wondering if there's any better way to accomplish this, or if there are any potential problems with doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Ruby's ***[coerce feature](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RubyCoerce).***

Comment: See also ["In Ruby, how does coerce actually work?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799571/in-ruby-how-does-coerce-actually-work)

Answer (score 1):

You want #coerce

something like

```
class Geom3d::Vector
    def coerce(right_hand_side)
       self,right_hand_side
    end
end
```

http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Vector.html