# Is there a ruby equivalent for rmul?

Tags: python, ruby

Is there a ruby equivelent for __rmul__ in ruby? I can't seem to find anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into things further, it seems the equivelent for rmul is to add

```
def coerce(other)
    return self, other
end
```

then have the usual * overloaded handle other types too with is_a?

Answer (score 2):

not sure about py, but is overloading operator `*` what you want?

if then, a method `*` will be fine.

```
a=Object.new
def a.*(rhs); rhs+2;end

a*2 #=> 4
```

Comment: rmul is slightly different, it is because you can have like 2*object OR object*2  I need somethign that runs on 2*object not object*2

Comment: in ruby, `2*object` is `like 2.*(object)`, and `object*2` is `object.*(2)`. so there is some difference, but not that different

Comment: What would it do if instead of 2, it was some other object, also with an overloaded * ?

Comment: to be more general, `a.*(b)` for `a*b` then.

Comment: I have posted the answer that seems to work fine for me now, but thankyou very much for the answer

Comment: glad if it helped maybe a little :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this discussion here about `coerce` in Ruby:

[In Ruby, how does coerce() actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799571/in-ruby-how-does-coerce-actually-work)