# How to implicitly convert custom class to integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, implicit-conversion

I have the following class:

```
class Register
  attr_accessor :val
  def initialize
    @val = 0
  end
end
```

I wish to be able to, given `ax=Register.new`, type `3 + ax` or `ax + 3` and get as a result the equivalent of `3 + ax.val`. I tried searching but can't find how this is done in Ruby.

Comment: Why would you want to?  What's wrong with using ax.val, which is unambiguous and works in the desired fashion?

Comment: The way I worded it,it does sound unneeded, but what I want this for is to be able to add together `Register`s with either `Fixnum`s or other `Register`s. So I need to be able to do both `ax + 3` and `ax + bx`, which, if using `val`, will not work for `Fixnum`s.

Comment: Still not seeing why `ax.val + 3` or `ax.val + bx.val` wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: If I do this in a method and want to add a variable, say `addend`, I will have to do a conditional statement on that variable, because I don't know if I want `addend` or `addend.val`. And I want to try to avoid that. It's for educational purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `ax + 3` to work, you need to define `+` method on your class:

```
def +(other)
  @value + other
end
```

However, `3 + x` will still result in an error as the interpreter won't have clue how to combine a `Fixnum` with the instance of your class. To fix this, define the `coerce` method like this:

```
def coerce(other)
  if other.is_a?(Fixnum)
    [other, @value]
  else
    super
  end
end
```

I won't go into detail on how `coerce` works as we already have a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2799899/1464605) here.

Comment: +1 for coerce. I was wondering how to achieve that in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will check out coerce, I think it's just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the method to the class:

```
class Register
  attr_accessor :val
  def initialize
    @val = 0
  end

  def +(x)
    @val + x
  end
end

a = Register.new
a + 5 # => 5
```

Note that, this method will allow you to call `a + 5` but not `5 + a`. You will get a `TypeError: Register can't be coerced into Fixnum` if you try.