# Converting a boolean sequence to an integer

Tags: ruby

I have four boolean variables `v0, v1, v2, v3` and want to get the integer expressed by them, taking the `v`'s as binary digits, and their values `false` as `0` and `true` as `1`, in other words:

```
8 * v3 + 4 * v2 + 2 * v1 + v0
```

What is the best way to cast them to such integers? Can this be done directly in a vector?

Comment: @CarySwoveland  Did you mean `D[v3]` as `D(v3)` did not work for me?

Comment: You could write 8*D[v3] + 4*D[v2] + 2*D[v1] + D[v0], where D = { true=>1, false=>0 }

Comment: @Wand, thanks. You're always so diplomatic. Aside: in your next avatar, how about you waving a magic wand?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just iterate. No need of power operation.

```
[false, true,  false, true] .inject(0){|n, b| n * 2 + (b ? 1 : 0)} # => 5
[false, false, false, false].inject(0){|n, b| n * 2 + (b ? 1 : 0)} # => 0
[false, false, false, true] .inject(0){|n, b| n * 2 + (b ? 1 : 0)} # => 1
[true,  false, false, true] .inject(0){|n, b| n * 2 + (b ? 1 : 0)} # => 9
```

Comment: I lean toward using `<<` as it is how we'd think of it in assembler.

Comment: This is one of the perks of learning a new language.  It is hard to understand just by looking at it, even while knowing what it does and being so short (as a newbie of course).  But then a quick Google on `inspect` and revisiting blocks and then it makes Ruby much richer.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a custom method:

```
def bool_to_int(bool)
  bool ? 1 : 0
end

8*bool_to_int(v3) + 4*bool_to_int(v2) + 2*bool_to_int(v1) + bool_to_int(v0)
```

You can of course use an array and apply the function call to all the values in the list.

```
ary = [false, true, true, false]

exp = 0
ary.inject(0) do |total, value|
  total += bool_to_int(value) * (2**exp)
  exp += 1
  total
end
```

This is more concise. The first item in the array is the exponent, the second is the sum.

```
ary = [false, true, true, false]
ary.inject([0,0]) do |(exp, total), value|
  [exp + 1, total + bool_to_int(value) * (2**exp)]
end
```

As pointed out in the comments, you can also use `<<`

```
ary = [false, true, true, false]
ary.inject([0,0]) do |(exp, total), value|
  [exp + 1, total + (bool_to_int(value) << exp)]
end
```

Comment: `n * (2**exp)` is equivalent to `n << exp`

Comment: You could also use `each_with_index` to avoid the array: `ary.each_with_index.inject(0) { |total, (value, exp)| total + (bool_to_int(value) << exp) }`

Answer (score 1):

In this certain example you could add `to_i` method directly to `true` and `false`:

```
def false.to_i
  0
end

def true.to_i
  1
end

def int_from_boolean_array(array)
  sum = 0  
  array.each_with_index do |el, index|
    sum += el.to_i * (2**index)
  end
  sum
end

int_from_boolean_array([false, true, false, true])
```

It works because `true` (same for `false`) is just simple object in ruby and thus you could extend it. Also you could write the same in slightly different way:

```
class TrueClass
  def to_i
    1
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def to_i
    0
  end
end
```

First approach works because there is always only one instance of `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` in the system.

Comment: It's not a good idea to monkey patch low-level classes such as TrueClass, without mention you are introducing a common cast method that can definitely cause a lot of side effects in many libraries. Just think about the effect it will have on duck typing (`respond_to?`) usage. This is a very terrible idea.

Comment: You could put it in a Refinement and only activate the Refinement within the scope of your own code.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I understand, that's why in the very beginning of the answer I've written "in this certain example".

Comment: Aside from this question, perhaps there's a case for `to_i` methods being added to Ruby's `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`.

Comment: The problem with that is False/false is not 0, it's more equivalent to nil. And 0 is more akin to true than it is false. For specific bit-twiddling code it'd be OK, but I can't see it part of the language itself because it'd cause havoc in the minds of those who are first encountering it.

Comment: This was my favorite answer because it seemed more natural.  After reading the comments -however- I understand the objection and will be more careful when using it.

Comment: @theTinMan Ruby's `pack/unpack` methods (especially big- vs little-endian) initially caused havoc in my mind, now they just bring on headaches.

Comment: I found it a lot easier to deal with low-level bit operations when I was writing assembly code, probably because everything is at that level. Dealing with anything from C and above ruined my ability to think in those terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can monkey-patch `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` to respond to `*` and `+` methods.  Here is a working solution largely based on discussion in this topic - [In Ruby, how does coerce() actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799571/in-ruby-how-does-coerce-actually-work)

```
# Changes to `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`
class TrueClass
    def *(i)
        i * 1
    end
    def +(i)
        i + 1
    end
    def coerce(something)
        [self, something]
    end
end

class FalseClass
    def *(i)
        i * 0
    end
    def +(i)
        i + 0
    end
    def coerce(something)
        [self,something]
    end
end

# Sample Runs

v3,v2,v1,v0 = true,false,true,true
p v3*8 + v2*4 + v1*2 + v0
#=> 11
p 8*v3 + 4*v2 + 2*v1 + v0
#=> 11
p 8*true + 4*false + 2*false + true
#=> 9
```

Comment: This is very insightful.  While I understand I shouldn't be monkeypatching, it helps understand the language.

Comment: Rails [Active Record Core Extensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) are pretty useful set of monkey-patching.