# How might I treat nil values as zero when adding numbers?

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

I have a method that looks like this:

```
def calculate_the_thing(hsh)
  hsh[:x] + hsh[:y] + hsh[:z]
end
```

which takes something like this:

```
{:x => 5, :y => nil, :z => 2, :a => 5}
```

I'd like to patch some classes so that when the `+` method gets a nil value, it treats it as zero. Seems reasonable. How might I do that?

Comment: nil.to_i already coerces to 0. So by using to_i on your inputs you get your desired behaviour by default. Defining nil to be equal to 0 in all contexts seems quite evil.

Comment: didn't know you could do that. That's a huge help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @jforberg points out, you can just use the `#to_i` method which will return 0 for nil.

```
def calculate_the_thing(hsh)
  hsh[:x].to_i + hsh[:y].to_i + hsh[:z].to_i
end
```

Alternatively, you can also define the hash with an automatic default value...

```
hsh = Hash.new{0}
```

But if you have a method that explicitly puts `nil` as a hash value that will override the default value.

Answer (score 5):

You need to monkey-patch `Nilclass` to coerce `nil` to an integer.  Here is the code:

```
class NilClass
  def coerce(n)
    return [0, n] if n.is_a? Numeric
    super
  end
end

1 + nil
#=> 1
```

---

Have a look at this thread - [In Ruby, how does coerce() actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799571/in-ruby-how-does-coerce-actually-work) - to understand the concept of `coerce`.

---

However, there is an issue with above code:

```
nil + 1
#=> undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

To fix this problem, you will have to define `+` method on `NilClass`

```
class NilClass
  def +(param)
    param  + self
  end
end

nil + 1
#=> 1
```

---

If we try to get adventurous and try:

```
nil * 10
#=> undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

By being adventurous, lets handle all such `undefined method`s by implementing our own `method_missing` handler.

```
class NilClass
  def method_missing m, *args, &block
    args.first.send(m, self, &block) if args.size == 1
  end
end

p nil * 1
#=> 0
```

---

Next, lets try:

```
nil + "hello"
# '+': can't convert NilClass to String (NilClass#to_str gives NilClass) (TypeError)
```

Lets fix this as well

```
class NilClass
  def to_str
    ""
  end
end

nil + "hello"
#=> "hello"
```

---

Next, lets try this:

```
nil + [1,2,3]
#=> '+': can't convert NilClass to Array (NilClass#to_ary gives NilClass) (TypeError)
```

Lets fix it:

```
class NilClass
  def to_ary
    []
  end
end

nil + [1,2,3]
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

---

We now have this version of `NilClass`:

```
class NilClass
  def coerce(n)
    return [0, n] if n.is_a? Numeric
    super
  end

  def method_missing m, *args, &block
    args.first.send(m, self, &block) if args.size == 1
  end

  def to_str
    ""
  end

  def to_ary
    []
  end
end
```

---

***Caution:***: Above code shows that what you want to do can be done.  However, this should be used only for experimental and learning purpose.  It is really not feasible to make `nil` behave like other operand in all operations and you will end up monkey-patching `NilClass` to no end.
Hence, its better to stay off from this kind of monkey patching to avoid scary surprises to future Rubyists who will be maintaining your code.

Comment: In almost all cases, this is a *really* bad idea as it goes against fundamental assumptions in ruby and can lead to hard to find bugs. Patching a core-class in that way should be avoided at all costs. The only way this could be use kind of safe is when using [Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html).

Comment: @HolgerJust Yeah, added a caution note  to the answer