# Ruby: How ist the .+ method working internally?

Tags: ruby, type-conversion, integer

Lets say I create an object a and give it a method .to_i, why can't this object be added to an Integer?

```
>> a = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x0000000006cfa9d0>
?> def a.to_int
?>   42
>> end
=> :to_int
>> 3 + a
(irb):5:in `+': Object can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)
        from (irb):5:in `<main>'
```

Thanks to Stefan it works!

```
irb(main):010:1* def a.coerce other
irb(main):011:1*   [other, 42]
irb(main):012:0> end
=> :coerce
irb(main):013:0> 1 + a
=> 43
```

Comment: It looks like you are looking for `coerce` method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799571/in-ruby-how-does-coerce-actually-work However this would only work for `3 + a`, for `a + 3` you would need to override `+` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an integer to an object can be achieved by implementing `+`, e.g.:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def to_i
    @value
  end

  def +(other)
    Foo.new(to_i + other.to_i)
  end
end

Foo.new(5) + 4
#=> #<Foo:0x00007fbd22050640 @value=9>
```

In order to add an instance of `Foo` to an integer, you have to also  implement `coerce` which takes the left-hand value as an argument and returns an array with both values converted to `Foo` instances, e.g.:

```
class Foo
  # ...

  def coerce(other)
    [Foo.new(other.to_i), self]
  end
end
```

This gives you:

```
4 + Foo.new(5)
#=> #<Foo:0x00007fba600e3e28 @value=9>
```

The docs for [`Numeric`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html) contain another example.

Internally, `coerce` is called by `Integer#+` if the argument is not an integer: (C code)

```c
VALUE
rb_int_plus(VALUE x, VALUE y)
{
    if (FIXNUM_P(x)) {
        return fix_plus(x, y);
    }
    else if (RB_TYPE_P(x, T_BIGNUM)) {
        return rb_big_plus(x, y);
    }
    return rb_num_coerce_bin(x, y, '+');
}
```

`rb_num_coerce_bin` calls `coerce` and then invokes the binary operator `+` on the returned values.

In Ruby this would be: (simplified)

```
class Integer
  def +(other)
    if other.is_a?(Integer)
      # ...
    else
      x, y = other.coerce(self)
      x + y
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect! coerce is the keyword. Thank you, once again!

Answer (score 1):

You still need to call the `to_int` method how else does the interpreter know what you want to do?

```
>> 3 + a.to_int
```

Ruby doesn't do automatic conversion.

```
>> 3 + "5"
```

This will give the same error, even though "5" has a perfectly fine to_i method. Btw. to int methods in ruby are ususally called `to_i` in case you want to keep the consistency.

Comment: Yes, you're right with `to_i`

Comment: `to_int` and `to_i` have very precisely defined meanings, and precisely defined use cases when it is correct to use `to_int` and when it is correct to use `to_i`. Saying "to int methods in ruby are ususally called `to_i` in case you want to keep the consistency" is very misleading because it has nothing to do with consistency and all to do with which method is the correct one.