# How do I implement a get method of instance of a class, and still access to object methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need to write an instance of a class to a variable and be able to access it both to get its value and to access its methods. Can I implement this somehow?

For example:

```
class A
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def preview
    puts "Class preview: #{@value}"
  end

  def something(param)
    puts "Something method: #{@value * param}"
  end
end

class B
  attr_reader :obj

  def set_object(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end
end

b = B.new
b.set_object(A.new(5))

b.obj # ==> 5
10 + b.obj # ==> 15

b.obj.preview # ==> "Class preview: 5"
b.obj.something(3) # ==> "Something method: 15"
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want `puts A` to print `5`? And `A + 10` to be 15?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental problem with your code is that you are implementing an object that behaves like a number, but without following Ruby's protocol for number-like types, as laid out by the [`Numeric`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Numeric.html) class.

In particular, you are missing the [*arithmetic coercion* protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2799899/2988) provided by the [`Numeric#coerce`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Numeric.html#method-i-coerce) method.

In Ruby, whenever an arithmetic operator does not know what to do with its operand, it will send the operand the `coerce` message and tell it to respond with a pair of operands it does know how to deal with.

For example, when send the `+` message to `10` and pass an instance of `A` as an argument, the method [`Integer#+`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Integer.html#method-i-2B) will be invoked. So, in this line:

```ruby
10 + b.obj
```

Here, you are sending the message `+` to the (result of evaluating the) [`Integer` literal](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Integer+Literals) `10`, and passing the result of evaluating the expression `b.obj` (i.e., an instance of `A`) as an argument.

So, what we have here is essentially:

```ruby
some_integer + some_a
```

Now, the problem is, of course, that `Integer#+` doesn't know how to add an instance of `A` to itself. However, every arithmetic operation observes the *arithmetic coercion* protocol, i.e., the implementation of `Integer#+` looks a little bit like this:

```ruby
class Integer
  def +(other)
    if other.is_a?(Integer)
      # I know what to do!
      # Do whatever internal magic computes the sum of two `Integer`s
    else
      coerced_self, coerced_other = other.coerce(self)
      coerced_self + coerced_other
    end
  end
end
```

Do you see the trick? `Integer#+` does not know how to add `Integer`s and `A`s, which is not surprising since you just wrote `A` today whereas `Integer#+` was written almost 30 years ago at this point. *However*, since `Integer` is a standard Ruby class, it assumes that `A` knows how to deal with `Integer`s!

So, what `Integer#+` does here, is that it calls `A`'s `coerce` method and says "Hey, I don't know what you are, but here I am passing myself as the argument, and I hope that *you* know what *I* am, so please convert myself and yourself to something that *does* know how to add the two together".

Which means, we need to implement a `coerce` method for `A`. The protocol for `coerce` is as follows:

- `coerce` gets sent to the *right operand* of the arithmetic operation with one argument, which is the *left* operand of the arithmetic operation.
- `coerce` needs to return a pair of objects `[coerced_left_operand, coerced_right_operand]`.
- `coerce` needs to ensure that this process eventually terminates, i.e., *at least one* of the two coerced return values should be *one step closer to a builtin type*.

So, let's implement `coerce`:

```ruby
class A
  def coerce(other) = [other, @value]
end
```

Now, if we run the code in the question, we get:

```
#<A:0x0000000101021cd0 @value=5>
15
Class preview: 5
Something method: 15
```

So, as you can see, the expression `10 + b.obj` was correctly evaluated to `15`.

The next problem with your code is that you are not overriding some of the standard methods that should always be overridden by objects. I am talking about methods like [`BasicObject#==`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/BasicObject.html#method-i-3D-3D), [`Object#eql?`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F), [`Object#hash`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Object.html#method-i-hash), [`Object#to_s`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Object.html#method-i-to_s), etc.

In particular, the message that is sent for displaying a human-readable debugging representation of an object, is `inspect`. We have not overridden [`Object#inspect`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Object.html#method-i-inspect), so we get the default implementation, which contains information about the class, an implementation-defined identifier, and a list of instance variables with their values.

We need to override `inspect` to work more like this:

```ruby
class A
  def inspect = @value.inspect
end
```

Now, running the code in the question, produces the desired result:

```
5
15
Class preview: 5
Something method: 15
```

There are a couple of other things that could be improved in your code.

- Since `A` is intended to be number-like, it should inherit from `Numeric`.
- Since `A` is integer-like, it should respond to `to_int`.
- Anything that responds to `to_int`, should logically also respond to `to_i`.
- Since `A` is number-like, it should implement the arithmetic operations.
- Almost always, a class should override `to_s` to provide a more sensible string representation.
- Almost always, a class should override `==` to provide more sensible equality semantics.
- Almost always, a class should override `eql?` and `hash` to provide more sensible set membership and hash semantics.
- In Ruby, setters (called *attribute writers* in Ruby) should not be prefixed with `set_`, instead they should be named `foo=`.
- Trivial attribute readers and writers should not be manually written, they should be defined using [`Module#attr_reader`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader), [`Module#attr_writer`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer), or [`Module#attr_accessor`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor).
- Objects should be fully valid after being created, there shouldn't be a need to call any setters or change any state to make them valid.

If we put this all together, we get something like this:

```ruby
class A < Numeric
  include Comparable

  def initialize(value)
    super()
    @value = value
  end

  def to_int = @value
  alias to_i to_int

  def to_s = @value.to_s
  alias inspect to_s

  def +(other)
    case other
    when A
      self.class.new(@value + other.value)
    when Integer, Float, BigDecimal, Rational, Complex
      self.class.new(@value + other)
    else
      raise(TypeError, "Don't know how to add #{other.inspect} of class #{other.class}") unless other.respond_to?(:coerce)

      coerced_self, coerced_other = other.coerce(self)
      coerced_self + coerced_other
    end
  end

  def -(other)
    case other
    when A
      self.class.new(@value - other.value)
    when Integer, Float, BigDecimal, Rational, Complex
      self.class.new(@value - other)
    else
      raise(TypeError, "Don't know how to add #{other.inspect} of class #{other.class}") unless other.respond_to?(:coerce)

      coerced_self, coerced_other = other.coerce(self)
      coerced_self - coerced_other
    end
  end

  def *(other)
    case other
    when A
      self.class.new(@value * other.value)
    when Integer, Float, BigDecimal, Rational, Complex
      self.class.new(@value * other)
    else
      raise(TypeError, "Don't know how to add #{other.inspect} of class #{other.class}") unless other.respond_to?(:coerce)

      coerced_self, coerced_other = other.coerce(self)
      coerced_self * coerced_other
    end
  end

  def /(other)
    case other
    when A
      self.class.new(@value / other.value)
    when Integer, Float, BigDecimal, Rational, Complex
      self.class.new(@value / other)
    else
      raise(TypeError, "Don't know how to add #{other.inspect} of class #{other.class}") unless other.respond_to?(:coerce)

      coerced_self, coerced_other = other.coerce(self)
      coerced_self / coerced_other
    end
  end

  def coerce(other)
    case other
    when Integer, Float, BigDecimal, Rational, Complex
      [self.class.new(other), self]
    else
      [other, to_int]
    end
  end

  def <=>(other) = to_i <=> other.to_i

  def preview
    puts("Class preview: #{self}")
  end

  def something(param)
    puts("Something method: #{self * param}")
  end

  protected

  attr_reader(:value)
end

class B
  attr_reader :obj

  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer really helped me figure it out.

Comment: A very in depth answer. Two notes. 1) I've never seen `def name = expr`! Is that shorthand for `def name return expr`? 2) "*you are not overriding some of the standard methods that should always be overridden by objects*" I'd strongly disagree with this as blanket advice, especially for folks new to Ruby. Overrides for standard methods must be carefully thought through and purposeful or you'll cause a big, hard to debug mess. New programmers love to try to solve problems with overrides and then they have more problems.